# anchor tags that avoid fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed header of 97px. I also have anchor tags set up that jump to each section of the page. The way my webpage is set out the anchor tags jump to the correct places by the titles of the pages are hidden behind the fixed header.

For this to work the way I want it to the anchor tags need to jump -97px from where they are currently jumping too?

How can I achieve this?

examples of my `href` jump to tags are:

```
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

    <a id="contact"name="contact"></a>
```

Comment: Jump tags = internal links

Answer (score 0):

There is a known hack involving setting the margin and padding on the anchor.

On your anchor ('jump') tag...

```
<a id="contact" style="padding-top: 80px; margin-top: -80px;">
```

See this website for an example:

http://mapleamonth.com/#how

Comment: tried this. any reason why it wouldn't work? It's not working? @itcouldevenbeaboat